# Why is this nth-child pseudo selector not working in the following table?

Tags: css

This is the CSS:

```
#signup .vedit tbody > tr.b_part3:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

The HTML structure:

[image]

As you can see, I want to select the second `.b_part` tr element of the table.

But for some reason the CSS rule is not being applied.

What could be the problem?

Live site: http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/signup4.php

Comment: Consider what `#signup .vedit tbody > tr:nth-child(2) ` would select then check if any of the selected elements would have the `b_part3` class.

Comment: @Musa Strange, that works. The second `tr` without the `b_part3` class gets selected.

Comment: And doesn't it index from 0? So if you wanted to select the 2nd one, it'd be `nth-child(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that @Musa teased out a solution to this problem, but I will add to that just to document in case others run into this issue.

As of right now you **can't** segment sections of siblings via classes AND use :nth-child().

```
    //Standard Use:
    ul li:nth-child(2) {  
      color: #0cf;
    }

    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li> <!-- Highlights Two -->
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>

    // Attempted Use:
    ul li.scope:nth-child(2) {  
      color: #0cf;
    }

    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li class="scope">One</li>
        <li class="scope">Two</li> <!-- Fails -->
        <li class="scope">Thre</li>
    </ul>

    // Optional Solution:
    ul.scope li:nth-child(2) {  
      color: #0cf;
    }

    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="scope">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li> <!-- Highlights Two -->
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
```

It appears that in order for the nth-child pseudo class to activate, it requires **direct** access to the element itself and not one of it's nodes. So for now the primary work around is to re-factor and take your scope up one level (or higher).

Answer (score 0):

Use `:eq()` instead of `:nth-child()` https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/